# Migrating sharepoint solutions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio

I have a sharepoint application on a certain server but, somehow it got corrupted and i have another fresh sharepoint server. Is there a way i can move the source code to the new server and run with visual studio and for it to execute normally. Pardon my English.

Comment: This depends on the level of corruption on your first server.  Can you access it?  If you can download the stored .wsp used and can still utilize the databases you are 90% there.

Comment: yes i can access it. Where do i get the .wsp from ?

Comment: Here is simple script: $farm = Get-SPFarm; 
$file = $farm.Solutions.Item("%solution_name%.wsp").SolutionFile;
$file.SaveAs("c:\temp\%solution_name%.wsp")  After transfer the solution file to a new server and deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

This will export all solutions in your farm:

```
(Get-SPFarm).Solutions | ForEach-Object { $var = "D:\Solutions\" + $_.Name; $_.SolutionFile.SaveAs($var)}
```

This will export only one solution :

```
(Get-SPFarm).Solutions | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "mySolutionName.wsp" } | ForEach-Object { $var = "D:\Solutions\" + $_.Name; $_.SolutionFile.SaveAs($var)}
```